Error: warning: refname ‘vX.Y.Z’ is ambiguous when running npx standard-version --dry-run
I’m encountering an issue when running npx standard-version --dry-run in my CI/CD pipeline. The command throws an unhandled error event related to an ambiguous refname. Here’s the error message:
npx standard-version --dry-run
node:events:490
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: warning: refname 'vX.Y.Z' is ambiguous.

